# Which programming language is best/most powerful for maths?

Tags: calculator, programming

Basically I need a programming language which I can use to do the following things, most/all of them with built in commands and functions instead of having to create my own logic/algorithms.

1) Get the value of 2 raised to the power 678932.

2) Find out whether 57656799 is a prime number or not.

3) Get factorial of 65655.

4) Get all possible partitions of the number 50.

5) Get number of digits in the number 787668768.

6) Get sum of all digits in the number 5444565464.

7) Convert 656755656.666676755 to standard form.

8) Convert 767576.000000004 to 3 significant figures.

9) Round off 56666566.67766 to nearest tens.

10) Find remainder when 65 is divided by 39.

11) Convert the number 675 to binary.

12) Get LCM or HCF of 13, 65, 90, 44, 5 and 3334.

13) Find out which number among 45, 7856, 335656, and -66 is greatest and which is smallest.

14) Get sum of all numbers from 67 to 980.

15) Get largest multiple of 7 between the numbers 89 and 557.

16) Find out whether 7656.00000 is an integer or a real number.

17) What is the seventh digit in the number 586857445653888.

18) Get Mean, Median and Mode of 2, 22, 2, 33, 2, 888888, 2, 5557, 4 and 6674.

19) Is a given number more than, less than or equal to 22.

20) How many 7s are there in the number 5645647777755557777778787907.

Truth be told, I am an 18 years old math geek who likes to make flowchart algorithms to do different things like get nth digit of the fibanachi sequence or find out whether a number is divisible by 3 or not and then translate that algorithm into code to use it on my laptop. While I don't indulge in things like calculus, trig or bionomial beyond school I often come across logics that I am not able to define with BODMAS or other functions of javascript (which I learned for this purpose but it turned out to be insufficient).

I know that a language that contains commands or functions every single one of the above mentioned stuff probably does not exist. However there must be a language that can still be used with some complex code to do all of it.

Comment: Look into using [Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/).  You can write programs in it with its own language, or have it interact with programs written in many of the other common languages.  See also [Matlab's wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB).  See also [wikipedia's list of alternatives to matlab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB#Alternatives).

Comment: C# with the Library numeric helped me a lot and it has all of what you asked include Big-integers, and you don't need to download the full visual studio, you could download SharpDevelop 5.1 (about 16 MB).

Comment: I like Python for many of these challenges because it does not have a maximum integer size (you are only limited by memory).  For instance it calculates $2^678932$ quickly and exactly with a simple command.  (You may not want to actually have it show the number on the screen though as it has over $200000$ decimal digits.  It has built in operators for some of your challenge.  Some of the challenges would require significant programming.

Comment: PARI/GP would be my favourite. But this is only my personal opinion.

Comment: I second Python. It might not have everything you want built in but it is easy enough to use that you should be able to figure out how to do most of what you want writing your own logic. There are also math based libraries for it like numpy, and it's all free unlike Mathematica and Matlab.

Comment: @Ahmad are u telling me C# can do all the stuff I mentioned?

Comment: @wgrenard MatLab is not free?

Comment: I recommend Python, because it's easy and very popular.  Unlike Matlab, Python is free. But you can do this stuff with any language, including C or C++.

Comment: Octave is the open source equivalent of MATLAB. Also, voting to close as too broad.

Comment: yes, you need to download a Library called **Numerics** ,it contains too much math, even a class for special function like $\Gamma$ , when i was dealing with too much math programming i found C# libraries for math very useful.

Comment: @SeanRoberson just given a language that is easy, can do all the above mentioned stuff and I can get the answer as a numerical value/s instead of strings or arrays because that would cause problems. then we will close

Comment: Nobody has spoken about CAS Mathematica, which allows to do a very wide range of things besides arithmetics (for which I agree that Pari is the most interesting). Unfortunately, Mathematica is expansive...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear: the title asks "best/most powerful for maths", the body lists things that look rather pedestrian, partially. So it depends. Those recommending Python do have their reasons: it's an easy to learn language, and it has integers of arbitrary length built in. It doesn't have very many mathematical functions in the language itself, but there are lots of libraries created by the aficionados. So it's not surprising that people who do a lot of numerical simulations (engineers and scientists) often prefer Python. Calling libraries written in other languages (Fortran, say) isn't difficult, so you have all the well-tested legacy code almost at your finger tips.
If you mean professional mathematics, if you want to handle objects like Taylor series, polynomials, quadratic fields, finite fields, p-adic numbers, elliptic curves as native objects of the language, you need Pari/GP. Imagine a looney who wants to integrate the differential equation of a pendulum, $\varphi''=-\sin\varphi$, with intitial conditions $\varphi(0)=\pi-0.001, \varphi'(0)=0$ from $0$ to $73$ with Taylor series, subdividing the whole interval into subintervals of length $0.3$, using $25$ terms of each Taylor series, and then plot the result. How many lines would that be in Python? Don't ask. In Pari/GP, that would be slightly over twenty, with the result (red: $\varphi$, green: $\varphi'$):
[image]

Pari/GP does have its shortcomings, naturally. It's not really much like other languages, the syntax is... erm... shall we say "ever so slightly ideosyncratic"?